# using jquery_datepicker in a form_tag form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a rails 3.1 datepicker using the jquery_datepicker gem - I want to provide the functionality to specify a date range (ie start and end date) that can be used in various views. So I have built a partial

#### app/views/shared/_date_range_form_content.html.erb

```
<div class='date_range'>
<%= form_tag "#{route}/#{id}" do %>
  <%= label_tag "Start Date" %>
  <%= datepicker_input nil, "start_date" %>
  <%= label_tag "End Date" %>
  <%= datepicker_input nil, "end_date" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I'm using a form_tag so I can pass the route (ie the controller that the form will be directed to) - this enables me to use this partial in multiple places.

The problem I am facing is with the datepicker_input. jquery_datepicker provides a form_for type method - but here I am using a form_tag. So Chrome's DevTools windows shows `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

What am I doing wrong? How would I put the datepicker into this form?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 0):

In the README you can see:

> Add this to your view.
>
> `<%= datepicker_input "user","birthday" %>`
>
> Where “user” is your model name and “birthday” the name of the
>   datefield.

So the `form_for` is not requires.

The `datepicker_input` helper:

```
def datepicker_input(object_name, method, options = {})
  datepicker(object_name, method, options)
end
```

I think the problem is that you are passing `nil` as the first param (`object_name`). Try passing a "valid" object instead of `nil` to debug the issue.

Comment: The question referred to using a non-model form, which is most easily done using a form_tag structure. You can produce a non-model object by creating a class, and adding in some ActiveModel modules, and a persisted? method - but it really is a faff. Thet then enables you to use form_for, which date_picker supports.

Comment: Try adding :foo instead of nil.